# Include html fragment if on one of a number of pages (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a pretty standard Rails 4 application at the moment with a number of static pages (home, about, contact etc) as well as the database backed pages. I want to include a html partial across most of the site but not on static pages (apart from the home page). I can get this working if I was stating just one page to exclude, for example the about page, using:

```
<% if !current_page?(about_url) %>
   include the partial
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure how to write this to have a list of urls, i.e. about_url, contact_url etc. I tried something along the lines of:

```
<% if [about_url, contact_url, ...].!include? current_page
```

but maybe not surprisingly it didn't work.

Is there a way to achieve this within the erb itself without going back to the controller? (I'm thinking I'd have to create the array for each controller)

Thanks for any help.

-- Update --

I just tried (following the comment below):

```
<% if not [about_url, contact_url].include? request.original_url %>
  <%= render partial %>
<% end %>
```

it doesn't appear to like this either. I'm not sure if my syntax if off again or it can't be done this way.

Comment: Try request.full_path and/or request.path instead of request.original_url

Comment: request_path did the trick! But I also needed to use about_path, contact_path in my array as opposed to about_url etc. I'll post the full solution as an answer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can go about doing this in many ways, one of which can be:

```
<% if current_page?(controller: 'YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME') && 
      (current_page?(action: 'about') || current_page?(action: 'contact') || ... ) %>
    include partial
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Vageesh, I was hoping to avoid the verbose strategy you have laid out. If I don't get anywhere then I'll revert back to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work but your syntax is off.

```
<% if [about_url, contact_url, ...].!include? current_page
```

should be

```
<% if not [about_url, contact_url, ...].include? current_page
```

Or if you prefer (but I prefer "not" since it's more readable)

```
<% if ![about_url, contact_url, ...].include? current_page
```

However, for readability and testability you should perhaps put that logic in the application controller or in a helper.

Comment: 'current_page?' is a helper that checks if current url was generated by given options. I dont think 'current_page' function/helper exists unless the user has defined it explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I just realised my error in this. Is there a way in Rails to get the current URL, i.e. that which I can directly compare to what's in the array?

Comment: I just updated my syntax (see update in main post) but still to no avail.

Comment: @VageeshBhasin I just assumed that since GerryDevine was using that variable he had defined it somewhere earlier.

Comment: @GerryDevine have you considered putting that logic away from the view  and in the controller or in a helper?

Comment: Actually yes, that's what Ive just been realising and am now trying to extract it out into a helper.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to the commenters I got it to work using the following:

```
<% if not [about_path, contact_path].include? request.path %>
  <%= render 'layouts/minibar' %>
<% end %>
```

** the main points being to use *_path to compare against request.path.